# How to use Sprite Kit setCenterRect in combination with flipping node through xScale?

Tags: sprite, sprite-kit, scaling

I hope someone can explain to me how the centerRect works and if it's bugged or not.

**IMAGE PIPE (64x64)**

[image: Pipe]

**STEP 1: CREATE PIPE**

```
SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Pipe"];
[self addChild:node];
```

**STEP 2: DEFINE CENTER RECT**

[image: CENTER RECT]

```
Origin (4.0, 32.0) Size( 56.0, 28.0)
```

As stated in the documentation:

> **(1)The rectangle is in the unit coordinate space**. The default value is
>   (0,0)-(1.0,1.0), which indicates that the entire texture is stretched
>   to fill the sprite. If a different rectangle is specified, then the
>   rectangle’s coordinates are used to break the texture into a 3x3 grid.
>   The four corners of this grid are applied without performing any
>   scaling. The upper- and lower-middle parts are scaled horizontally,
>   and **(2) the left- and right-middle parts are scaled vertically**. The center
>   is scaled in both directions.

1. How can you figure out the unit coordinate space?
2. If the left and right middle parts are scaled vertically and the center scaled in both directions the code becomes:

   ```
   SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Pipe"];
   [node setCenterRect:CGRectMake(4.0/64.0, 32.0/64.0, 56.0/64.0, 28.0/64.0)];
   [node setYScale:4.0];
   [self addChild:node];
   ```

***Result***

[image: Result]

Weird the outcome is not what I expected, I don't want the top part to stretch, only the bottom part. Perhaps that has to do with the unit coordinate space?? I presume a flipped coordinate space.

**STEP 3: LETS TRY AGAIN WITH REVERSED COORDINATES**

[image]

```
SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Pipe"];
[node setCenterRect:CGRectMake(8.0/64.0, 8.0/64.0, 56.0/64.0, 28.0/64.0)];
[node setYScale:4.0];
[self addChild:node];
```

***Result***

[image]

Not really what I expected, but at least now the proper part got stretched. So I guess that worked, but maybe someone can shine some light on why.

**STEP 4: FIX APPEARANCE**

```
[node setCenterRect:CGRectMake(8.0/64.0, 8.0/64.0, 56.0/64.0, 22.0/64.0)];
```

[image]

**STEP 5: LETS FLIP**

So far, so good. We got the bottom pipe, now let's create the top pipe by first flipping it vertically.

```
    SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Pipe"];
    [node setCenterRect:CGRectMake(8.0/64.0, 8.0/64.0, 56.0/64.0, 22.0/64.0)];
    [node setYScale:-4.0];
    [self addChild:node];
```

***Result***

[image]

Wooaah! It got all messed up?!?!! Let's take a step back and only flip it horizontally.

```
    SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Pipe"];
    [node setCenterRect:CGRectMake(8.0/64.0, 8.0/64.0, 56.0/64.0, 22.0/64.0)];
    [node setXScale:-1.0];
    [node setYScale:4.0];
    [self addChild:node];
```

***Result***

[image]

Okay, that's really messed up. I have no idea how this works??

**STEP 6: CUSTOM SCRIPT**

I hope someone can tell me how the centerRect works in combination with the xScales, but for now I am creating a different sprite node and do the flip there (which is not ideal).

```
- (SKSpriteNode *)spriteNodeWithFlippedImageNamed:(NSString *)name
{
    UIImage     *image      = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    CGImageRef  imageRef    = image.CGImage;
    float       scale       = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    CGSize      size        = CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height);

    //begin context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //flip image
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1.0, -1.0);

    //draw tiling image
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, (CGRect){CGPointZero, CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height)}, imageRef);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //create node
    SKTexture       *texture    = [SKTexture textureWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage];
    SKSpriteNode    *node       = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture size:size];

    return node;
}
```

**SUMMARY QUESTIONS**

1. How can you figure out the unit coordinate space?
2. How can you use the `setCenterRect` methode in combination with flipping the sprite?

Comment: Use 'setCenterRect' for what!?

Comment: In general. I have a couple of sprites in which I use the centerRect to properly scale the image without stretching the complete image.

Comment: For instance, I have a bottom en top pipe. I only have one image of a pipe, it doesn't have to scale the top part only the bottom part. Which works when using the reverse coordinates. However when I use the same image for the top pipe where I need to flip the image, I get all sort of weird outcomes when using xScale -1 and centerRect.

Comment: I don't use centerRect.  And I don't get my images stretched out for my universal games.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this myself. Whatever I did centerRect did not work as expected, not as described, not even in a way that makes it seem it follows a specific set of rules.

Comment: I rewrote my question it's now more detailed. Thanks for your comment at least I won't feel alone now ;)

Answer (score 0):

for the 1st question:

You should use percent coord for centerRect property like your Step 2.

The problem here is just your origin position, you should use left bottom corner as 0,0 instead of left top corner.

Hope this help!

Comment: Is there a way you can change that origin? so 0,0 is left top?

Answer (score 0):

I found that inverting the CGRect (shape) when I know I'm flipping the spritenode seems to work -- notice the larger "y" value and negative sign for the "height" in the CGRect when we want the pipe flipped (i.e., pointing "Down")

** Updated for Swift, not Objective-C as originally noted above **

```
enum PipeDirection: Int {
    case Up = 1
    case Down = -1
}
```

...

```
// Scale pipe larger from center area only (i.e., don't scale pipe "caps")
if pipeDirection == .Up {
    pipe.centerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.2, width: 1.0, height: 0.4)
} else {
    pipe.centerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.8, width: 1.0, height: -0.4)
}
pipe.yScale = CGFloat(pipeDirection.rawValue) * 1.5
```